# what is inquiry url while creating a UDDi registry ,when i go to publish a web service?

Tags: java, web-services

while creating a UDDi registry its ask for inquiry url what is it??

Answer (score 0):

It's the URL the client apllications will access for finding the information of the services stored at your UDDi registry.
It's different from the *Publishing URL*, wich is used to register services.

More information:

- [UDDI: Universal Description, Discovery, and Integration, Part 2](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/jws_6/index2.html)
- [InformIT: UDDI Inquiry with Java](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=102228)